# Object in StyleSheet in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'd like to know if there is something like what can be done in .less with StyleSheet object in React Native to group some objects.

For example if I render something like this :

```
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
   <View style={styles.wrapper.left}></View>
   <View style={styles.wrapper.right}></View>
</View>
```

and have a stylesheet object like this :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    /* Some properties */,
    left: {
      /* Some properties */,
    },
    right: {
      /* Some properties */,
    },
  }
})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **getter** for this purpose

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

you can use this with **StyleSheet.create**

```js
let style = {
  wrapper: {
    color: "red",
    position: "absolute",
  },
  
  get left() {
    return {
      ...this.wrapper,
      left: 0,
    };
  },
  
  get right() {
    return {
      ...this.wrapper,
      right: 0,
    };
  },
};

console.log(style.left)
```

```js
let style2 = {
  wrapper: {
    prop: {
      color: "red",
      position: "absolute",
    },

    get top() {
      return {
        ...this.prop,
        top: 0,
      };
    },
    get bottom() {
      return {
        ...this.prop,
        bottom: 0,
      };
    },
  },
};

console.log(style2.wrapper.bottom);
```